# Help in solving nonlinear system of equations

Tags: lie-algebras, nonlinear-system

I have a system of six non-linear equations in six unknowns, which I do not know how to solve.

$$\left( 1 + 4 \left( x_2^2 + x_3^2 \right) \right)x_4 - 4x_1x_2x_5 - 4x_1x_3x_6 = 0,$$
$$-4x_1x_2x_4 + \left( 1 + 4 \left( x_1^2 + x_3^2 \right) \right)x_5 - 4x_2x_3x_6 = 0,$$
$$-4x_1x_3x_4 - 4x_2x_3x_5 + \left( 1 + 4 \left( x_1^2 + x_2^2 \right) \right)x_6 = 0,$$
$$\left( 1 - 4 \left( x_5^2 + x_6^2 \right) \right)x_1 + 4x_4x_5x_2 + 4x_4x_6x_3 = 0,$$
$$4x_4x_5x_1 + \left( 1 - 4 \left( x_4^2 + x_6^2 \right) \right)x_2 + 4x_5x_6x_3 = 0,$$
$$4x_4x_6x_1 + 4x_5x_6x_2 + \left( 1 - 4 \left( x_4^2 + x_5^2 \right) \right)x_3 = 0.$$

As a start, I have added the first three equations and the last three equations to try and get a perfect square. In the process, I have:

$$\left( 1 + 2 \left( x_1 + x_2 + x_3 \right)^2 \right) \left( x_4 + x_5 + x_6 \right) - 2 \left( 2x_2x_3 + x_1^2 \right)x_4 - 2 \left( 2x_1x_3 + x_2^2 \right)x_5 - 2 \left( 2x_1x_2 + x_3^2 \right)x_6 = 0,$$
$$\left( 1 - 2 \left( x_4 + x_5 + x_6 \right)^2 \right) \left( x_1 + x_2 + x_3 \right) + 2 \left( 2x_5x_6 + x_4^2 \right)x_1 + 2 \left( 2x_4x_6 + x_5^2 \right)x_2 + 2 \left( 2x_4x_5 + x_6^2 \right)x_3 = 0.$$

From here, I have no idea how to proceed! Is there any general method to solve a system of nonlinear equations? Any help will be appreciated!

---

PS: The system is only a part of a system of $90$ equations in $36$ unknowns which I obtained when trying to find a Lie algebra isomorphism between $\mathfrak{so} \left( 3; 1 \right)_{\mathbb{C}}$ and $\mathfrak{sl} \left( 2, \mathbb{C} \right) \oplus \mathfrak{sl} \left( 2, \mathbb{C} \right)$. Most of the equations in the system are of this form, and if I can solve this system, I suppose the other $30$ variables can be known easily.

Comment: Have you looked at Gröbner basis and Buchberger's algorithm?

Comment: I have no idea about solving nonlinear systems.

Comment: Loosely speaking Buchberger's algorithm does to polynomial equations what Gaussian elimination does to linear equations.

Comment: For what it's worth, [Buchberger's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchberger%27s_algorithm) is implemented in [sage](https://sagemath.org), which is a free and open source computer algebra system. There's a tutorial for solving systems of polynomial equations using sage [here](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/11070/find-algebraic-solutions-to-system-of-polynomial-equations/), though for the system outlined in your problem sage isn't able to find a solution. Maybe if you tried it with all 90? Good luck! ^_^

Comment: I tried to solve it with Maxima (https://maxima.sourceforge.io/) but it couldn't either. More equations could help reduce the basis further.

Comment: Surely there are better ways to find homomorphisms between those Lie algebras.

Comment: I have solved the equations by considering first other equations in addition. Moreover, we only need to find *one* isomorphism, not any one. So we can make choices.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, yes! Indeed there are better ways. That require the knowledge of a proper basis for $\mathfrak{sl} \left( 2, \mathbb{C} \right)$. But, right now I only know two basis: One given in Hall's book (which, I suppose is quite standard everywhere) and the other one composed of Pauli's spin matrices. So, instead of having trial and error with bases, I tried to get the isomorphism by assuming that the images of the basis elements of $\mathfrak{so} \left( 3; 1 \right)_{\mathbb{C}}$ as linear combinations of the basis elements of the codomain and they satisfy commutation relations.

Comment: A very strong restriction on the variables also is that the determinant of the matrix representing the isomorphism has to be nonzero. This excludes many solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Using [Maxima](https://maxima.sourceforge.io/)

```
load(grobner);
vars : [x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6];

eqns : [(1+4*(x2^2+x3^2))*x4−4*x1*x2*x5−4*x1*x3*x6,
−4*x1*x2*x4+(1+4*(x1^2+x3^2))*x5 −4*x2*x3*x6,
−4*x1*x3*x4 −4*x2*x3*x5+(1+4*(x1^2+x2^2))*x6,
(1−4*(x5^2+x6^2))*x1 + 4*x4*x5*x2 +4*x4*x6*x3,
4*x4*x5*x1+(1−4*(x4^2+x6^2))*x2 + 4*x5*x6*x3,
4*x4*x6*x1+4*x5*x6*x2+(1−4*(x4^2+x5^2))*x3];

eqns : expand(eqns);

gb : poly_reduced_grobner(eqns,vars);
```

$$\begin{pmatrix} -4\,x_{1}
 \,x_{3}\,x_{6}-4\,x_{1}\,x_{2}\,x_{5}+4\,x_{3}^2\,x_{4}+4\,x_{2}^2\,
 x_{4}+x_{4}\cr -4\,x_{1}\,x_{6}^2+4\,x_{3}\,x_{4}\,x_{6}-4\,x_{1}\,
 x_{5}^2+4\,x_{2}\,x_{4}\,x_{5}+x_{1}\cr x_{3}\,x_{6}+x_{2}\,x_{5}+
 x_{1}\,x_{4}\cr 4\,x_{1}\,x_{2}\,x_{6}^2-4\,x_{1}\,x_{3}\,x_{5}\,
 x_{6}-4\,x_{2}\,x_{3}\,x_{4}\,x_{6}+4\,x_{3}^2\,x_{4}\,x_{5}+x_{4}\,
 x_{5}-x_{1}\,x_{2}\cr -4\,x_{2}^2\,x_{6}^2+8\,x_{2}\,x_{3}\,x_{5}\,
 x_{6}-4\,x_{3}^2\,x_{5}^2+x_{4}^2+x_{3}^2+x_{2}^2\cr 4\,x_{4}\,x_{6}
 ^2+4\,x_{4}\,x_{5}^2+4\,x_{4}^3-x_{4}\cr -4\,x_{6}^3-4\,x_{5}^2\,
 x_{6}-4\,x_{4}^2\,x_{6}+x_{6}\cr -4\,x_{5}\,x_{6}^2-4\,x_{5}^3-4\,
 x_{4}^2\,x_{5}+x_{5}\cr -4\,x_{3}\,x_{6}^2-4\,x_{3}\,x_{5}^2-4\,
 x_{3}\,x_{4}^2+x_{3}\cr -4\,x_{2}\,x_{6}^2-4\,x_{2}\,x_{5}^2-4\,
 x_{2}\,x_{4}^2+x_{2}\cr -x_{6}^2-x_{5}^2-x_{4}^2-x_{3}^2-x_{2}^2-
 x_{1}^2\cr \end{pmatrix}$$

All these equations are equal to $0$.

The last equation gives $x_{6}^2+x_{5}^2+x_{4}^2+x_{3}^2+x_{2}^2+
 x_{1}^2 = 0$

Looking at the equations they seem to be very symmetric.

It implies that some more properties/equations are needed to differentiate the variables.